# flutter windows issue: When I go to select image from desktop gallery

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop, flutter-windows

Please help!
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your plugin is not supporting the windows.

Answer (score 0):

To use that plugin on Windows, you need to add the [`image_picker_windows` package](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_windows). It's still in early stages, so isn't included by default with `image_picker`.